# Subclass of declarative_base cannot be garbage collected?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning sqlalchemy and want to use it in my project. Because my project involve a tree structure and a lot of nodes, I want to free the memory after the object is persisted in the DB.

But when I did some tests for sqlalchemy for this, it just confuses me that the object created won't be garbage collected.

Here's my test code:

```
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, Column, select, case,
func, ForeignKey)
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, MapperExtension, aliased
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import weakref
import sys
import gc

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class Cursor(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cursor'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    spelling = Column(String, nullable = True)
    displayname = Column(String, nullable = False)
    usr = Column(String, nullable = True)
    is_definition = Column(Boolean, nullable = False)

    type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('type.id'))
    type = relationship('Type',
                        backref = backref('instances', order_by = id))


class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'type'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)

    is_const_qualified = Column(Boolean, nullable = False)


obj_type = Type(is_const_qualified=False)
type_ref = weakref.ref(obj_type)

print sys.getrefcount(obj_type)

obj_type = None
print type_ref()
```

which gives me the following output:

```
3
<__main__.Type object at 0x268a490>
```

So after I set the `obj_type` to None, it's still not garbage collected and still alive.
Why will this happen? Is this the mechanism of `declarative_base`?

Note that I am using Python 2.7.3 and sqlalchemy 0.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works better in SQLAlchemy 0.8, however in 0.7.9 there's just a cycle somewhere.  When testing gc you always need to call `gc.collect()` to collect cycles:

```
obj_type = None
gc.collect()
print type_ref()
```

in 0.8 the `collect()` isn't needed for this particular test if cPython is used.

Comment: I tried it, and it does work in 0.8.1. Thank you.
So this is the problem of old version of `relationship`?

Comment: I couldn't say specifically but overall you shouldn't rely on Python garbage collection being immediate.  Cycles occur all the time and also interpreters like Pypy and Jython do GC totally differently.